# Change decorator's parameter inside function

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, breadcrumbs

I am using flask-breadcrumbs add-on for python flask web server,
but I think this is more general question of python decorator,

```
@app.route('/dashboard')
@register_breadcrumb(app, '.', parameter)
def render_dashboard_page():
 ...
```

is it possible to set "parameter" from within the function "render_dashboard_page"?
I need parameter to be chosen based on "Accept-language" flag of the request, which I can determine only after the method was fired.

By the way, the 3rd input of "@register_breadcrumb" is the breadcrumb item title and I want it to be localized based on the "Accept-language" flag.

more information about the add-on: http://flask-breadcrumbs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to pass arguments to a function's decorator from inside the function, as the decorator executes before the function is defined. A guide on how decorators work can be found [here](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=240808) and [here](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=240845) - essentially, the decorator is a function that is passed the function below it, and then returns a function that should be inserted into the namespace.

Easier to give an example:

```
>>> def add_one(fn):
...     print("add_one called")
...     def wrap(n):
...         print("wrap called")
...         return fn(n) + 1
...     return wrap
>>> @add_one
... def times_by_two(n):
...     print("times_by_two called")
...     return n * 2
add_one called
>>> times_by_two(21)
wrap called
times_by_two called
43
```

I'm not entirely sure how that Flask plugin works, but you might be able to use the [variable rules](https://flask-breadcrumbs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#variable-rules) feature to do what you want. It looks like you can define a function to be called which returns text and a URL for the last component of the breadcrumbs, and the `request` object is accessible from that function; hopefully that's enough to be able to determine the user's language.